# SPARQL DBpedia filter out specific results

Tags: filter, sparql, ontology, dbpedia

I am working on a small part where I receive all types of a resource. The thing is: I don't want to have all types, only the "http://dbpedia.org/ontology"-types. How do I filter them within a SPARQL query? I don't really care as long I receive only the ontologies.

In this query I need only the dbpedia-Ontologies "Country", "Location" "PopulatedPlace" and "Place".

SPARQL endpoint: http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql

```sql
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?type WHERE {
?i rdfs:label "Deutschland"@de ; a ?type .
}
```

I set up a `FILTER` which filters out the Ontologies. But that's not the solution as it is static and only works for this example. It also duplicates. But that's a minor problem.

```sql
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?type WHERE {
?i rdfs:label "Deutschland"@de ; a ?type .
FILTER (?type = <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country> ||
?type = <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace> ||
?type = <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place> ||
?type = <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Location>)
}
```

Need some suggestions or help. Thx in advance.

Comment: This are DBpedia classes (or maybe types) - I don't understand why you call them "dbpedia-Ontologies"?

Comment: `DISTINCT` can be used to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i thought i shouldn't have asked, but this took me some time to realize... There is a function to filter when a string starts with the same letters...

```
 strstarts
```

Solution. Hope i could at least help someone.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?type WHERE {
?i rdfs:label "Deutschland"@de ; a ?type .
FILTER (strstarts(str(?type), "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"))
}
```

Comment: And even without this function, there is always the REGEX support - although this might be slower for the current use-case.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to use `GROUP BY` here. Like in SQL the operator `DISTINCT` can be used: `SELECT DISTINCT ?type WHERE ...`

Comment: Thank you a lot, much easier then. I'm still rather new to SPARQL.

Answer (score 0):

Well what you did is fine but probably not the correct way of doing it. What you're looking for are called owl classes. So you just need to check if the type that you're looking for is an `owl:Class` or not.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT ?type WHERE {
?i rdfs:label "Deutschland"@de ; a ?type .
?type a owl:Class .
}
```